# 2 looks like a 4 in the tex.se font

Tags: discussion, bug, design, fonts

When using OpenSuSE 11.3, the font for titles, votes and views counts has a very odd-looking character "2". It has an unusual serif-like crossing in the bottom part (sorry, I don't know the exact terminology in typography for calling that line).

It might be just me, but it took me a while to figure out that it is a 2 and not a 4 with a curved upper part. Besides, that font looks horribly baroque and unreadable to my eye.

The offending typeface seems to be OpenSuSE's version of Palatino.

Comment: I am not sure I get what you mean. Maybe you could make a screenshot and illustrate the confusion of '2' for '4'?

Comment: @N.N. It the same font that appears in Martin Schröder's answer here below.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug that is fixed in an updated version of the software/browser.

Comment: @Werner I agree, but it is a 2-year old discussion, and I don't think it was off-topic when it started. I've accepted an answer to close it, anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be an OpenSuSE bug: https://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2011-January/028355.html

Comment: Confirmed; it's fixed in OpenSUSE 11.4.

Answer (score 10):

Surely you're seeing something we're not. Here's an image of the votes and view count font on my system (Firefox 10.0 on a Mac):

[image: vote count image]

I really don't see how the 4 and the 2 are very similar, and although the font is serifed  it doesn't seem very baroque to me (although obviously this is a matter of opinion.)

Answer (score 7):

This is what I'm seeing (with FF10 on OpenSUSE 11.3 with KDE):

[image: 2 looks like 4]

Comment: ...and why is this?

Comment: What font is ff10 using?

Comment: I am using Firefox 10.0 (in Ubuntu 11.10) and I do not see this.

Comment: @PatrickGundlach: I confirm that I see the ugly font on OpenSuSE 11.3 with both FF10 and Chrome 16, but not on Ubuntu with the same FF10. So it must be a SuSE font problem. How do I check which font is actually being used?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I don't know. I've tried whatthefont and didn't succeed. Perhaps the firebug inspector can help? The site requests "Palatino Linotype",Palatino,"Hoefler Text","Book Antiqua",Georgia,serif -  so any of those are probably chosen.

Comment: @PatrickGundlach The culprit is Palatino.